# Add row value to previous row value in R

Tags: r

I have a very basic question as I am relatively new to R. I was wondering how to add a value in a column to the previous value and repeat right down a column of 1000s of values? Note, I do not want a cumulative sum and therefore the cumsum function is of no use. Say my column is called WD, I want to add WD1 to WD2, WD2 to WD3, WD3 to WD4 etc. all the way down and output these sums as a new column. Is there an easy way? Many thanks.

A reproducible example:

```
set.seed(111)
df1 <- data.frame(WD=sample(10))

#result
df1
   WD new
1   6   6
2   7  13
3   3  10
4   4   7
5   8  12
6  10  18
7   1  11
8   2   3
9   9  11
10  5  14
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We add the current row (`WD[-nrow(df1)]`) with the next row (`WD[-1L]`) and concatenate with the first element to create the column.

```
df1$newColumn <- with(df1, c(WD[1],WD[-1]+WD[-nrow(df1)]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much akrun - a very simple solution that works perfectly. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @DJ-AFC No problem.  Glad to know that it helped you.

Answer (score 3):

Another option, using `lag()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(df1, new = WD + lag(WD, default = 0))
```

Or using `shift()` from `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, new := WD + shift(WD, fill = 0)]
```

**Note**: The default type of `shift()` is "lag". The other possible value is "lead".

Which gives:

```
#   WD new
#1   6   6
#2   7  13
#3   3  10
#4   4   7
#5   8  12
#6  10  18
#7   1  11
#8   2   3
#9   9  11
#10  5  14
```